# Opening a project in AppCode

Tags: swift, appcode

I just downloaded and am trying out `AppCode` (but am a veteran user of multiple other *JetBrains* Ide's..) I have tried to open a few different projects but nothing happens.

An example is `tensorflow/swift-models/Examples/BERT-CoLa`

[image]

I click on `Open` but then nothing happens: we end up back here:

[image]

So either `AppCode` behaves differently than all of its other `JetBrains` friends or something is broken (and I do not know what that *something* is)

Any pointers?

Comment: Where is the `.xcodeproj`

Comment: I haven't used AppCode myself, but if it can import Swift Package Manager packages, the swift-models project has a core Swift package at its root level. At least in Xcode, if you open up the swift-models directory, you can select, build, and run the BERT-CoLA. The BERT-CoLA example itself doesn't have a discrete SwiftPM package or Xcode project, it's a target within the larger swift-models package.

Comment: @BradLarson I had actually tried that also at the parent level: still no dice. I will update the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppCode won't open just a folder - it needs `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` in this folder, e.g. regular Xcode project. Other project models (such as CMake or pure SwiftPM projects without the generated Xcode project) are not supported.